# What is the advantage of 6 Directional Movement vs, for instance, 8 or 4

Tags: c++, game-design

I'm making a fallout 2 inspired game and I'm wondering what you guys think about its use of 6 directional movement. It kind of bugs me for some reason and seems like it would make game play odd and programming it would be more difficult than 8 directional movement it seems.

Any thoughts?

Comment: At the moment, this question is really open-ended. I think that might explain the downvotes. It's hard to answer with anything "correct". Maybe this could be made more answerable as something like *Why would you design a 6-directional movement system over an 8-directional one?*. (Also, could you explain what 6-directional is? I've never played Fallout.)

Comment: @Anko: It's been a while since I played it, but I think its maps were hex grids and you could only move between cells, which means you can move in six directions to the neighbouring cells. As for the question itself, I agree it's not very answerable right now.

Answer (score 2):

Hexagons as a grid type are not uncommon in games, particularly games involving tactical elements.

In a 4-way movement scheme, in order to move diagonally you have to expend two moves.
In a 8-way movement scheme, you either have to make the diagonal moves have a cost of two, one, or a fractional sqrt(2) cost in resources.

Hexagonal grids allow movement along three axes with equal cost, which lessens the impact of which way the grid is laid out.

Programming with hexagonal grids is not hard. You store staggered rows of the grid and indexing is very cheap.

Comment: Hmm, thanks! Great response, gives me a lot to think about